# SQLAlchemy polymorphic many-to-many relation with abstract base in declarative syntax

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, declarative

I am creating a SQLAlchemy declarative model with many-to-many relation where one of the tables is concrete and another is polymorphic with abstract base.

**Use case:** I am sending messages which contain multiple components (component1, component2) and each component has very different set of attributes (so each of the components has own database table). A component can be sent in multiple different messages.

I would like to have a M:N relation between the Message class and an abstract parent class called Component - but **the database shouldn't contain any abstract "component" table**, only tables for concrete children ("component1", "component2" etc.).

I tried to combine [abstract 1:N relation using AbstractConcreteBase](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/inheritance.html#using-the-declarative-helper-classes) (see the last/3rd code snippet in this chapter) with [regular M:N relation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) into the following code which fails to find the name of table for abstract base class:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, AbstractConcreteBase

BaseModel = declarative_base()

association = Table("message_component_association", BaseModel.metadata,
    Column("message_id", Integer, ForeignKey("message.id")),
    Column("component_id", Integer, ForeignKey("component.id")))  # Fails to reference the Component class

class Message(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "message"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    components = relationship("Component", secondary=association, back_populates="messages")

class Component(AbstractConcreteBase, BaseModel):
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity="component", concrete=False)  # This seems to be ignored

class Component1(Component):
    __tablename__ = "component1"
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity="component1", concrete=True)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    messages = relationship("Message", secondary=association, back_populates="components")

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
BaseModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The exception says:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'message_component_association.component_id' could not find table 'component' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

Why are the **mapper_args** of Component class ignored and the class cannot be found via provided polymorphic_identity?

**EDIT:** I've realized I can use Joined Table Inheritance (grr, I cannot post more than 2 links) which replaces the declarative helper mixin by explicit discriminator to get a polymorphic M:N relation - but still, **the base class needs own database table**.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

BaseModel = declarative_base()

association = Table("message_component_association", BaseModel.metadata,
Column("message_id", Integer, ForeignKey("message.id")),
Column("component_id", Integer, ForeignKey("component.id")))

class Message(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "message"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    components = relationship("Component", secondary=association, back_populates="messages")

class Component(BaseModel):  # Declarative mixin removed
    __tablename__ = "component"  # Requires a real DB table despite being abstract
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity="component", polymorphic_on="type")  # Apply the discriminator
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(32))  # Explicit discriminator
    messages = relationship("Message", secondary=association, back_populates="components")

class Component1(Component):
    __tablename__ = "component1"
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity="component1")
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("component.id"), primary_key=True)  # Shares the primary key sequence with the parent and with all other child classes
    messages = relationship("Message", secondary=association, back_populates="components")

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
BaseModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session(engine)

component_1 = Component1(id=1)
session.commit()
```

The code seems to work so far but it **complains about issues with flush**. Is it safe to ignore the warning as long as I don't manually write to the "components table" -- or is there a better way?

```
SAWarning: Warning: relationship 'messages' on mapper 'Mapper|Component1|component1' supersedes the same relationship on inherited mapper 'Mapper|Component|component'; this can cause dependency issues during flush
```

Comment: Link to the Joined Table Inheritance: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** Remove all relationships except the one at Message class and replace back_populates with backref. Backref will create the opposite direction on the fly and the mapper will not see overridden relationships. Also, the polymorphic_identity on the abstract ancestor is not necessary.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

BaseModel = declarative_base()

association = Table("message_component_association", BaseModel.metadata,
Column("message_id", Integer, ForeignKey("message.id")),
Column("component_id", Integer, ForeignKey("component.id")))

class Message(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "message"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    components = relationship("Component", secondary=association, backref="messages")  # backref instead of back_populates

class Component(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "component"
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_on="type")  # Polymorphic identity removed
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(32))

    # relationship removed

class Component1(Component):
    __tablename__ = "component1"
    __mapper_args__ = dict(polymorphic_identity="component1")
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("component.id"), primary_key=True)

    # relationship removed

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
BaseModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session(engine)

component_1 = Component1(id=1)
session.commit()
```